# How to make this program follow 2 conditions?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I have some code which I want to follow two conditions.
`ans` can be m/f and `ans1` can be b/m/l 
How can I connect them?

```
if (ans == 'm') + (ans1 == 'b') {
    total = (((((9.99 * result2) + (6.25 * result3)) - (4.92 * result1)) - 161) * result4) + 1000;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You need " + total + " calories to maintain weight");
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `if (ans == 'm' && ans1 == 'b')` or did I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested if statements :

```
if (ans == 'm') {
    if (ans1 == 'b') {

    } else if (ans1 == 'm') {

    } else if (ans1 == 'l') {

    }
} else if (ans == 'f') {
    if (ans1 == 'b') {

    } else if (ans1 == 'm') {

    } else if (ans1 == 'l') {

    }
}
```

Or you can use if statements with conditional AND :

```
if (ans == 'm' && ans1 == 'b') {

} else if (ans == 'm' && ans1 == 'm') {

} else if ...
```